# Why does the screen be Black when I run my app on a device or in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I need some help with trying to fix a problem when I run my app, either on a Device or in the iOS simulator it show a black screen but if I press the home button and then tap on app it shows all the content. Does anyone know what is actually happening?

[Picture Of Simulator via Black Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIFFs.png)

import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate{

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FIRApp.configure()
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
     return true

}

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Comment: Post your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Your app is already running in fact, but your are not handling its background foreground states

Comment: voting for closure as the question is too broad and unclear to properly answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your rootviewcontoller view are two link views so remove all and other textfields and UIlabel remove. then run the application.

```
 //remove Newview in this picture
```

[image]

> And I think the second solution is set rootviewcontoler
>   programmatically.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {
             self.window!.rootViewController = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rootviewcontoller")     
        }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I have 2 solutions which are of course very broad:

1. I guess your project doesn't have quite a lot of stuff. The best would be just redo it from scratch. Pretty sure you made some small mistake that you can't really find out and we can't too without seeing your code.
2. Recall what you did so that it became like this (showing black screen) and revert your code and see what really made this black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. After reading the console logs, I realized that `GoogleService-Info.plist` isn't added to project in Xcode even though I copy the file and put it into the project directory. To solve the problem, manually add `GoogleService-Info.plist`into Xcode. Click `File` -> `Add File to project` and select the file. Run the project again and the problem should be fixed. Happy coding!